# Ruby dynamically redefined class methods not present in include

Tags: ruby

I opened HTTParty module and redefined get and post class methods at runtime using following:

```
define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
  method = method(method_name)
  method(hook).call(*args)
  method.call(*args, &block)
end
```

Here, `hook` is name of another method in HTTParty module. `method_name` can be either get or post.

After that I tried to include HTTParty in TestClient class as following:

```
class TestClient
  include HTTParty
  ...
end
```

but the versions of get and post methods included are original ones only. Shouldn't it use the redefined methods?

Comment: Can you post more context around your `define_singleton_method`? What do `method`, `hook`, etc refer to? How do you know your redefined methods aren't being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because when you do `define_singleton_method`, the receiver is the `HTTParty` module, not the class it's included in (which doesn't yet exist when `define_singleton_method` is invoked). So when you `include HTTParty` in `TestClient`, your redefined `get` was already bound to `HTTParty`, and invoking it on `TestClient` wouldn't reach it. However, if you did `HTTParty.get("http://google.com")`, you'd get your redefined methods:

```
  module HTTParty
    %i{ get post }.each do |method_name|
      define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
        puts "redefined!"
      end
    end
  end

  class TestClient
    include HTTParty
  end
  TestClient.get("http://google.com")
  # real GET
  TestClient.method(:get).source_location 
  # ["/Users/kitkat/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576@kitkat/gems/httparty-0.13.7/lib/httparty.rb", 475]
  HTTParty.get("http://google.com")
  # => redefined!
  HTTParty.method(:get).source_location
   => ["(irb)", 30]
```

And here's how you can really redefine your methods:

```
  module HTTParty
    def self.included(klass)          
      %i{ get post }.each do |method_name|
        klass.define_singleton_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
          puts "redefined!"
        end
      end
    end
  end

  class TestClient
    include HTTParty
  end

2.0.0-p576 :058 >       TestClient.get("http://google.com")
redefined!
 => nil
2.0.0-p576 :060 >         TestClient.method(:get).source_location
 => ["(irb)", 48]
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. When HTTParty module gets included in TestClient, its redefined methods like original ones should be accessible too, right? Is there a way to include these methods in TestClient?

Comment: Yep, added it to my answer!

Comment: I have some more questions about extended problem.

Comment: I am trying to provide before_action kind of feature. So, method redefining is being handled by Hooks::ExecutionHooks module. This module is included in HTTParty module.
Now, this HTTParty module is getting included in TestClient class.
How should I handle this scenario?

Comment: Hmm, are you saying you have to use `Hooks::ExecutionHooks` instead of `define_singleton_method`? I'm not familiar with `Hooks::ExecutionHooks`; where does it come from? I didn't see it in the [HTTParty source](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/blob/master/lib/httparty.rb).

Comment: Logic of redefining get and post methods is present in ExecutionHooks module which I have written.